# How to create a tar ball of few files in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

I have few images which i want to archive and make a tar ball file,

Please if you have any reference or sample code , will be helpful

Thanks in advance for everyone

Kamal

Answer (score 0):

You might try http://www.feep.net/libtar/ or http://sourceforge.net/projects/libxad/

Comment: i have tried but is this for iPhone, i dont think so ,,, Could you please confirm the same

Thanks for your answer and support

Comment: The easiest way to find out if these work on the iPhone is to download and try them.  You should probably be able to get away with adding the .c and .h files for them to your iPhone project.  Just make sure the license for them is compatible with the binary distribution on the App Store (talk to a lawyer if you're not clear on this).

And if they don't work, tar isn't exactly a hard format to write on your own -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(file_format) -- quickly looking, you should easily be able to write something to suit your needs since there is nothing complex about tar.

Answer (score 0):

Confused with the question.  Are you trying to create a TAR ball on the Mac?  In that case, just right click on the file(s) and choose Archive.

Or are you trying to make a TAR ball on the iPhone?  In that case, can you just do an NSThread and invoke TAR?  I would expect it to be included with the iPhone.  If not, there are public (free) versions that you could compile and include with your distribution package.

Comment: only jailbroken iPhones have tar installed. It's not a part of the standard iPhone OS filesystem.